# Python code to copy lines from one text file to other till matching text is found

Tags: python

Lets say my abc.txt file contains below lines

```
Information: 
Device 1 information is displayed below 
Device name is ABCD
Firmware version is 1.0.0
Hardware version is 1.0.0
Software version is 0.0.1
Flashed date 1-1-2020
Information: 
Device 2 information is displayed below
Device name is EFGH
Firmware version is 1.0.1
Hardware version is 1.2.0
Software version is 0.0.1
Flashed date is 2.1.2020
Information: 
Device 3 information is displayed below
Device name is IJKL
Firmware version is 1.0.1
Hardware version is 1.2.0
Software version is 0.0.1
Flashed date is 3.1.2020
```

Copy lines till next "Information" string is found in abc.txt file to xyz.txt file.

Expected output in xyz.txt:

```
Information: 
Device 1 information is displayed below 
Device name is ABCD
Firmware version is 1.0.0
Hardware version is 1.0.0
Software version is 0.0.1
Flashed date 1-1-2020
```

abc.txt file to uvw.txt file.

```
Information: 
Device 2 information is displayed below
Device name is EFGH
Firmware version is 1.0.1
Hardware version is 1.2.0
Software version is 0.0.1
Flashed date is 2.1.2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `string.split()` can do your work.

```
lis = string.split('Information: Device')
```

This will output

```
['',
 ' 1 information is displayed below Device name is ABCD Firmware version is 1.0.0 Hardware version is 1.0.0 Software version is 0.0.1 Flashed date 1-1-2020 ',
 ' 2 information is displayed below Device name is EFGH Firmware version is 1.0.1 Hardware version is 1.2.0 Software version is 0.0.1 Flashed date is 2.1.2020 ',
 ' 3 information is displayed below Device name is IJKL Firmware version is 1.0.1 Hardware version is 1.2.0 Software version is 0.0.1']
```

This can be now further modified as

```
lis.remove('')
for i in range(len(lis)):
    lis[i] = 'Information: Device' + lis[i]
```

This will output the required result, i.e.,

```
['Information: Device 1 information is displayed below Device name is ABCD Firmware version is 1.0.0 Hardware version is 1.0.0 Software version is 0.0.1 Flashed date 1-1-2020 ',
 'Information: Device 2 information is displayed below Device name is EFGH Firmware version is 1.0.1 Hardware version is 1.2.0 Software version is 0.0.1 Flashed date is 2.1.2020 ',
 'Information: Device 3 information is displayed below Device name is IJKL Firmware version is 1.0.1 Hardware version is 1.2.0 Software version is 0.0.1']
```

All the list elements can now one-by-one be appended to different txt files.